# How to format phone number in a lightning web component without click to dial behavior?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm trying to show a phone number to a user, in a lightning web component, so that when they click on the number, it populates an input box.

LWCs have the [lightning-formatted-phone](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-phone/example) component, however clicking on this triggers a click-to-dial event.

[The specification](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-phone/specification) for the component says it has a "click" method, but doing this:

```
<lightning-formatted-phone
    value="+18005551212"
    onclick={myHandler}>
</lightning-formatted-phone>
```

Doesn't fire `myHandler` in the component, so I can't stopPropagation() nor preventDefault().

My question is **how can I show a formatted phone number in a LWC with custom click behavior?** Can this be achieved with the standard formatted phone input, or is there another Salesforce-y way to do this?

Comment: There is a strong chance that the "Click-To-Dial" event is being triggered from your browser, not from SFDC. I'd try different browsers to double-check.

Comment: I edited my answer with an example playground, I am able to call preventDefault() in the click handler.

Answer (score 1):

The `click-to-dial event` is coming from the standard HTML protocol `tel:`. Your browser is looking for it and if available it tries to dial that phone number when you click on it. The `<lightning-formatted-phone>` component looks like so when it builds in the browser:

[image]

> `tel:` is not so much a feature as it is a protocol, much in the same way that `http:` and `mailto:` are protocols for the  tag feature

[Source](https://css-tricks.com/the-current-state-of-telephone-links/) and [Source2](https://davidwalsh.name/phone-link-protocol).

In order to prevent the `click-to-dial` action you need to get rid of the `tel:` part of the `<a>` element. Since this is an out of the box component provided by Salesforce this functionality is internally handled and you can't modify it.

What you need to do, in order to prevent this from happening, is format the phone number yourself using a standard html element such as a `<span>` or a `<div>`.

I put a playground together to show you how you can easily mimic what the SF component does. You can check it out [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/LjP-3AhpG/3/edit).

All you have to do is add a `<span>` element and style it like so:

**HTML**

`<span class="phone-link" onclick={myHandler}>+18005551212</span>`

**CSS**

```
.phone-link {
    color: #006dcc;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.phone-link:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

However a potential complexity for you could be the formatting of the phone number yourself using JavaScript.

Comment: The tel: information is useful, but this doesn't answer the question. If the answer ends up being "there's no other way except to manually implement a javascript formatting function" i'll probably just delete the question, because it's no longer a salesforce specific answer

Comment: As I pointed out in my answer the way to do is it to get rid of the "tel:" in the `lightning-formatted-phone` which you have no control over. So there's no way to achieve what you are asking using the out of the box functionality for formatting a phone number.

Answer (score -1):

Call `event.preventDefault()` in your handler.

EDIT: I missed the part where he said his handler wasn't getting called, but that sounds like an isolated issue. onclick handlers do get called an I'm able to use preventDefault(): [Example Playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/32k7kKoRi/9/edit)